# Heroku only one table being created - sinatra/ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, sinatra, psql

so locally everything works fine. I have 2 simple tables in my DB, i have some migration files and everything. I've been trying to push to heroku for the past hour or so but it's not working. Only 1 table is being migrated, but the second one isn't. I tried creating other migration, but nothing works. Here's my schema:

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20140804004043) do

  # These are extensions that must be enabled in order to support this database
  enable_extension "plpgsql"

  create_table "folders", force: true do |t|
    t.string "name"
    t.string "description"
  end

  create_table "ifolders", force: true do |t|
    t.string "name"
    t.string "description"
  end

  create_table "ifoldersx", force: true do |t|
    t.string "name"
    t.string "description"
  end

  create_table "images", force: true do |t|
    t.string  "name"
    t.integer "folder_id"
    t.string  "description"
    t.string  "url"
  end

end
```

I've tried heroku restart. heroku pg:reset DATABASE. but nothing is working.

Is there a way I can manually add the table into heroku, perhaps with command prompt or something?

Thanks!

EDIT:
Migration Files:

```
class CreateImages < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :images do |t|
      t.string  :name
      t.integer  :folder_id
      t.string  :description
      t.string :url
    end
  end
end

class CreateIfolders < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :ifolders do |t|
      t.string  :name
      t.string  :description
    end
  end
end

class CreateIfoldersx < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :ifoldersx do |t|
      t.string  :name
      t.string  :description
    end
  end
end

class CreateFolders < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :folders do |t|
      t.string  :name
      t.string  :description
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: If you have a Rake command for running migrations you could use [`heroku run rake`](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rake)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are also re-migrating the database

```
heroku pg:reset DATABASE
heroku run rake db:migrate
```

If that doesn't work add your migration files into your question.

You can easily check if its working by starting up rails console on heroku

```
heroku run rails c
```

Edited...

Next step would be to jump in and see what the heroku logs are saying with `heroku logs --tail` and

```
$ heroku run rails c
File.open('log/production.log', 'r').each_line { |line| puts line }
```

Comment: I'm not sure what the issue is, I still haven't figured it out, but i switched to Padrino, I assume something was wrong with my migration files.

Comment: can you add your migration files to your question?